# How can I bind a list of radioes with dynamic binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, radio-button, dynamic-binding

I wanna bind a list of controls in my controller.

I don't have any problem with text box, check box or drop down.

For instance,

```
@Html.TextBox("tblContactPhones[0].description")
@Html.DropDownList("tblContactPhones[0].phoneLable", PhoneType)
@Html.TextBox("tblContactPhones[1].description")
@Html.DropDownList("tblContactPhones[1].phoneLable", PhoneType)
```

These have same names that bind dynamically in my controller.

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(tblContact entity)
```

as u see these names aren't same

but I cant do this for a radio group.

they have to have same names for correct selecting.

and I can't bind this in a list.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to worry about names.

As the main overloads of the `@Html.RadioButton()` helper are the following:

```
@Html.RadioButton(string name, object value)
@Html.RadioButton(string name, object value, bool isChecked)
```

So:

1) if you want 2 rdoBtns as a true/false fashion:

```
@Html.RadioButton("IsSomething", true)
@Html.RadioButton("isSomething", false)
```

2) If you have a collection of values - for example an enum:

```
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item1)
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item2)
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item3)
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item4)
```

Note that you can pass a `true` value as the 3rd parameter to the helper to indicate that item should be checked by default:

```
// This rdo is selected by default
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item1, true) 
@Html.RadioButton("FavoriteItem", MyEnum.Item2)
// other rdoBtns ...
```

Comment: Thank u. But you didn't say any things about binding. My problem is dynamic radio button list binding.

Comment: @VBYOFSKI - As you said that you don't want to use model binding and html helpers, I thought that you handled that... Manual model binding in server side can be achieved by use of `Request["name"]` or `FormCollection`. If this tip isn't enough, tell me so that I update my answer...